# Subtracting a value that is result of a sum

Tags: mysql, sql

My query below works perfectly but I need to change one part of my calculation for a new metric.

Currently it's presenting the data like this (removing unnecessary columns for sake of space and time):

```
ID | Extension | Total Inbound | Total Outbound | Total Missed | Total Calls
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      1000          6              1                 2             7
```

However, I want to change it to subtract missed from inbound. It needs to continue to add inbound and outbound for the total but I'm looking for this output:

```
ID | Extension | Total Inbound | Total Outbound | Total Missed | Total Calls
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      1000          4              1                 2             7

Insert into test.ambitionLog30Days(Extension, ExtID, Total_Talk_Time_seconds,
       Total_Talk_Time_minutes,Total_Outbound, Total_Inbound, 
       Missed_Calls, Total_Calls, Time_of_report,Date_of_report  )  
    SELECT 
        c.extension 
       ,RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID 
       , sum(Duration)  
       , round(sum(Duration) / 60,2) 
       , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 1,1,0)) -- Total inbound calls 
       , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 2,1,0)) 
       , sum(if(Answered = 1,0,1)) -- Total Missed calls
       , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 1,1,0)) + sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 2,1,0))   as total_calls 
       , b.ts
       , b.ts 
    FROM cdrdb.session a
    INNER JOIN cdrdb.callsummary b
        ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
    INNER join cdrdb.mxuser c
        ON a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID = c.EXTENSIONID
        WHERE b.ts BETWEEN curdate() - interval 30 day and curdate()
    -- WHERE b.ts >= '20170723' and b.ts < '20170823'
    AND c.extension IN (7276,7314,7295,7306,7357,7200,7218,7247,7331,7255,7330,7000,7215,7240,7358,7312)
    group by c.extension,b.ts
    ON duplicate key update Total_Talk_Time_seconds =values(Total_Talk_Time_seconds), 
       Total_Talk_Time_minutes =values(Total_Talk_Time_minutes), 
       Total_Outbound = values(Total_Outbound), 
       Total_Inbound = values(Total_Inbound), 
       Missed_calls = values(Missed_calls), 
       Total_Calls = values(Total_Calls),
       Time_of_report = values(Time_of_report);
```

I tried subtracting  `- sum(if(Answered = 1,0,1))` on the total inbound line but it just returned the values in my outbound columns as negative numbers so I think I just have some syntax wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do the calculation:

```
SELECT c.extension, 
       RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID ,
       sum(Duration),  
       round(sum(Duration) / 60, 2) ,
       sum(LEGTYPE1 = 1 and Answered = 1), -- Total inbound calls 
       sum(LEGTYPE1 = 2), 
       sum(case when Answered = 1 then 0 else 1 end)), -- Total Missed calls
       sum( LEGTYPE1 in (1, 2) ), as total_calls 
       b.ts
```

I also simplified the logic, by removing the `if()`.  MySQL allows you to treat boolean expressions as numbers, with 1 for true and 0 for false.  Note that missed can be expressed as `sum( Answered <> 1 )`, if `Answered` is never `NULL`.

Comment: why not `sum(Answered <> 1` :). otherwise, nice.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works great! Is there a better way for me to calculate total to add the value from all 3 total columns?

Comment: @TomN. . . . I would be inclined to use `count(*)` somewhere.